# HTML/CSS Table height ignored in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, html-table

I'm adding a new 'News Container' to a slightly older webpage at our firm.
This container is made up of a 2x3 table. I want the Cell 2x2 to be as High as the Text.

Here's the Problem:
Everybody uses IE in our offices (Security reasons etc.) but for some reason IE ignores the height attribute given either directly in HTML (style="height:;" or height="") or in a separate CSS.
So in Chrome it looks like this (how it should):

```
╔════════════════╗
╠══╦═════════════╣
║  ║Test String  ║
║  ╠═════════════╣
╚══╩═════════════╝
```

And in Internet Explorer like this:

```
╔════════════════╗
╠══╦═════════════╣
║  ║Test String  ║
║  ║             ║
║  ╠═════════════╣
╚══╩═════════════╝
```

Picture: http://imgur.com/a/jQXhQ

View it yourself (Open in both Chrome and IE) [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/razuliserm/UzCRc/22/)

How can I get IE to use the Height attribute or alternatively is there a different way?
IE Version: 11.0.9600.17358
Update: 11.0.13

Code:

```
<table id="NewsTable">
<tr>
    <th id="NewsHeader" colspan="2">IT Status</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img id="NewsAmpel" alt="NewsStatus" src="Ampel/AmpelA.jpg" width="36px" height="100px">
    </td>
    <td id="NewsStatus"><b>Status:&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</b>Test String</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="NewsDesc"><b>Description:&emsp;</b>Sample Text</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Which version of IE is this?

Comment: @Joeytje50 Good point I'll add that to the question. It's IE 11

Comment: The linked jsfiddle works just fine for me in IE11. Could you link to a screenshot (upload it to http://imgur.com/ and put the link in a reply here) to show how it looks in IE?

Comment: @Joeytje50 Weird. Here you go: http://imgur.com/a/jQXhQ

Comment: i have updated the answer please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have made some changes in html as well as CSS

### Working Fiddle

[**http://jsfiddle.net/UzCRc/60/**](http://jsfiddle.net/UzCRc/60/)

HTML

```
<table id="NewsTable">
    <tr>
        <th id="NewsHeader" colspan="2">IT Status</th>
    </tr>      
    <tr>
        <td id="NewsAmpel">
            <img  alt="NewsStatus" src="Ampel/AmpelA.jpg" width="36px" height="100px">
        </td>
        <td id="NewsStatus"><b>Status:&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</b>Test String</td>
        <td id="NewsDesc"><b>Description:&emsp;</b>Sample Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
#NewsAmpel{   
    width:36px;
}

body {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    body {
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    img {
        border: 0;
    }
    a {
        color: #00538E;
    }
    #content {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
    }
    #center {
        width: 600px;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    font-weight: bold;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
a {
    color: #00538E;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#center {
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#NewsTable {
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
}
#NewsStatus {
    height: 20px;
    padding:0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    display:block;
}
#NewsDesc {
    height: 20px;   
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:block;
}
#NewsHeader {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: #FF1000;
}
```

**Changes in html**

1. Removed colspan
2. added image TD in same TR
3. Instead of image, ID has given to TD

**CSS changes**

```
#NewsStatus {
    height: 20px;
    padding:0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 100%;//modified
    vertical-align: top;
    display:block;//added
}
#NewsDesc {
    height: 20px;  //added 
    width: 100%;//modified
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:block;//added
}
#NewsAmpel{   
    width:36px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome but the next Cell now starts way below the Text of the first one any Idea how to fix that?

Comment: Works great on Fiddle but for some reason the full version doesn't want any of it. http://imgur.com/tfM3CGW except for the Strings being in German I didn't change anything from your solution though.

Edit: seems to work fine in chrome though http://imgur.com/a/WazPx

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/WazPx I see whats happening here now. IE is ignoring the display: block; from #NewsStatus and #NewsDesc

Comment: Thanks. But that broke things even more. The NewsStatus is now outside of the box/border. I'm starting to feel like this has todo with the inhouse IE install.